# json schema issue on required property

Tags: json-schema-validator

I need to write the JSON Schema based on the specification defined by http://json-schema.org/. But I'm struggling for the required/mandatory property validation. Below is the JSON schema that I have written where all the 3 properties are mandatory but **In my case either one should be mandatory**. How to do this?.

```
{
    "id": "http://example.com/searchShops-schema#",
    "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
    "title": "searchShops Service",
    "description": "",
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {     
            "city":{
                "type": "string"                
            },  
            "address":{
                "type": "string"                
            },      
            "zipCode":{
                "type": "integer"
            }                   
    },
    "required": ["city", "address", "zipCode"]
}
```

Comment: As JSON is nothing but a cheap copy of xml, simply check their specification if they have something correlating to ``xsd:choice`` (http://www.w3schools.com/schema/el_choice.asp).

Comment: It appears the keyword is "one-of", as shown here: http://json-schema.org/example2.html . Under "The entry schema - adding constraints".

Comment: What do you mean by "either one should be mandatory"? Do you mean that at least one property should be present?

Comment: @user2225104 you are misled to a high degree; JSON and XML have nothing to do with one another. Also, that more people are moving from XML to JSON (which is basically the lingua franca for data exchange over HTTP nowadays) is no accident.

Comment: @fge Curly braces or angled brackets - What makes both systems alike is that it consists of a syntax for writing data sets (in Text documents), that one needs something like a Schema Description language and hey - XPath is very nice, too. JSON was advertised as the more "human reader/writer" friendly as xml, which IMHO completely missed the point. Now, gradually JSON habitat tries to catch up, adding Schema language and maybe one day even an analog to XPath. So how else could one label it but a cheap copy of Xml with a slightly different syntax?

Comment: @user2225104 "JSON was advertised as..." <-- by whom? Certainly not by me and please note that I am the author of two of the three JSON Schema drafts. As to XPath, there is JSON Path which is not defined yet but also JSON Pointer which is an RFC. Those are tools which are necessary to efficiently process data, but we try and do not reproduce the mistakes of XSD!

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is to tell that "I want at least one member to exist" then use `minProperties`:

```
{
    "type": "object",
    "etc": "etc",
    "minProperties": 1
}
```

Note also that you can use `"dependencies"` to great effect if you also want additional constraints to exist when this or that member is present.

Answer (score 0):

```
{
  ...
  "anyOf": [
    { "required": ["city"] },
    { "required": ["address"] },
    { "required": ["zipcode"] },
  ]
}
```

Or use "oneOf" if exactly one property should be present